# Problem deploying webservice "Could not create type 'Service'

Tags: asp.net, web-services, deployment, parse-error

I have big trouble deploying my webservice. It is the basic helloWorld start webservice.

At my localhost everything os ok. But when I copy the service to my server in my virtual directory  i recieve this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'Service'.
>
> Source Error: Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="vb" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.vb" Class="Service" %>
>
> Source File: /customers/iv_webservice/Service.asmx    Line: 1
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955

Now I have tried almost everything. Including scanning the web for the past 9 hours for an answer.

I know my virtual directory in the web.config is ok, since I have other virtual websites on my server. I even manage to have aspx. files in the same directory and they are ok.

Now, what am I missing?

Comment: It appears that you are using a web site, not a web application project. I strongly recommend that you not use web sites for anything serious. You've hit one of the reasons for that.

Answer (score 0):

Does your web service use a 3rd party assembly or unmanaged Dll that is not deployed to the server?  In my experience "cannot create object of type" errors are missing *unmanaged* Dlls.  In the case of missing managed assemblies, the error will usually tell you which assembly is missing.

Comment: I create it as a web-projekt without dll's. Ill try to see, if it is the hotst provider, that disabled the webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try compiling the service.vb as an standalone assembly? That might help understand any dependencies you might not be satisfying.. You might also see additional information in Event viewer or if you set the debug mode to true in web.config to see if there are any errors reported compiling service.vb.

Comment: Is is ok as a stand alone. Everything works like a charm. I try to contact the hostprovider, to see if something is wrong at their end. Ill update this page with the answer.